# Matplotlib toolbar missing "figure settings" button

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

I am using python Anaconda on Windows.
When I plotted a figure with pyplot.plt(), the toolbar with the home, zoom ecc buttons appears. 
I recall there was a last button, like a green tick, that allowed editing the plot settings (eg linestye ecc, see below) 
[image]

For some mysterious reason I don't see this button anymore. How can I have it back?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same matplotlib backend?

Comment: You are right, the matplotlib backend was the issue..thank you

Answer (score 0):

The matplotlib backend was the issue. Switching from TkAgg to Qt4Agg solved the problem